# Is this the correct way to raise an Exception? (Python)

Tags: python, exception, error-handling, runtime-error

```
for i in range(1,1000):
    try:
        x = some_crazy_function(my_parm(i))
        if x in massive:
            raise Exception()
        massive.append(x)
        x = dict(qnother_crazy_functionsl(x.replace('X','Y')))
        x = new_func(x['constant'])[0]
        next.append(x)
    except:
        break
```

I'm fairly new to python and I ran cross this fragment  while maintaining someone else's code

To me that looks like a horrible way to exit a loop. 
Is it the accepted way to code in python and I'll get used to it or is it as bad as it looks?

Comment: Exceptions are raised when your code encounters something abnormal. There is nothing abnormal about `x` being in `massive` - unless, of course, you would normally expect `x` _not_ to be in `massive`. Performance-wise, exceptions are very expensive. So, use `break` instead.

Comment: Use of the bare `except:` is also a bad idea, since it also catches `KeyboardInterrupt` and a few other things you probably don't want to catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the simplest of cases, a `break` would be the best (and simplest) way to break out of a loop:

```
if x in massive:
    break
```

However, if throwing and catching an exception is more apt for your use case, I would recommend first *defining* your own user defined Exception class:

```
class MassiveException(Exception):
    pass
```

Next, you can throw it like this:

```
if x in massive:
    raise MassiveException()
```

And consequently catch it like this:

```
except MassiveException:
    ... # do something here
```

This is better because it makes your intent clear, and also gets rid of the catch-all except which will swallow other exceptions you *really* don't want swallowed.

Comment: Thanks all.  As I said it looked like a bad way to code, and your responses would seem to reinforce my feeling. Thanks for the code snippets for a better way to implement this fragment.

Comment: re: accepted Sorry but while I understand the concept I am clueless on implementation. and how do I get a linefeed in here?